# Javascript confirm box always returns true

Tags: javascript, jsp

This is my code for confirmation box. When i press `OK` it should call the delete function. When I press `Cancel` it should return to the home page, but the file is deleted even though I choose `Cancel`. This is my code. What is wrong ?

```js
var response = confirm ("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this user?");  

if (response)  
{  
  <% String userName =request.getParameter("userName");      
     del.del(userName);
   %> 
  window.location.href='adminHome.jsp';
}
else
{
  window.location.href='adminHome.jsp'; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
<% String userName =request.getParameter("userName");
del.del(userName);%>
```

runs on your **server** before the page is even sent to the browser, and therefore the user is gone before you even get to the `confirm()`.

You'll have to introduce an explicit new HTTP request, either by simply posting a form or else via ajax, and handle that at the server. That request would only be triggered when your confirmation returns `true`.

Comment: i dont know how to use ajax requests can u please show me an example?

Comment: @nallas well it's a big topic; luckily there are lots and lots of tutorials available on the web.